# PHP Websocket Client

Tags: php, laravel, wss, fsockopen, laravel-websockets

I'm currently attempting to create a WebSocket client to connect to a wss:// URL with PHP (without using JavaScript). It's been a few days trying to program a simple function or class that can do so.

I tried and looked into `fsockopen`, various streams, and also Racket but failed to see in their docs a client class. Is this possible with PHP? Code sample or any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: It is 100% possible with PHP. Show us your code and problem so it can be solved.

Comment: It's certainly possible. Don't re-invent the wheel though - [start here](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+websocket+client)

Comment: Thank you guys your comments gave me courage to look further. Found the solution. Any other tips and tricks more than welcome maybe it helps others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone looking in the future this is what I found and used. Walk in the park.

[PHP-WSS](https://github.com/arthurkushman/php-wss)

```
<?php
use WSSC\WebSocketClient;
use \WSSC\Components\ClientConfig;

$client = new WebSocketClient('ws://localhost:8000/notifications/messanger/yourtoken123', new ClientConfig());
$client->send('{"user_id" : 123}');
echo $client->receive();
```